# Match of phonenumber from sms and database

Tags: android, sqlite

Please note that the number prefix, +45, is used as an example since I'm from denmark.

As part of an app I have a database table with blacklisted phone numbers. But some numbers under my contacts are stored as +45 xx xx xx xx, others as +45xxxxxxxx and yet others as xx xx xx xx.

Incoming texts arrive with the number format +45xxxxxxxx.

I've created a simple provider which I query like seen below.

```
private boolean isBlacklisted(String phoneNumber)
{
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(Provider.URI_BLACKLIST,
        new String[] { Blacklist.COL_PHONE_NUMBER },
        Blacklist.COL_PHONE_NUMBER + " = ?",
        new String[] { phoneNumber },
        null);
    return(cursor.getCount() > 0);
}
```

What do you guys suggest to make proper matching? Considering international standards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following lib seems to provide proper formatting.

https://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/